# SAS: How do I Store a Macro in a Catalog

Tags: sas, sas-macro

This is a follow up question to a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39502208/sas-how-do-i-put-entries-into-a-catalog).  I am trying to store a macro in a catalog as outlined by these articles, in addition to the resources cited in my original post:

- [PROC CATALOG, the Wish Book SAS® Procedure](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings15/3459-2015.pdf)
- [Ways to Store Macro Source Codes and How to Retrieve Them](http://analytics.ncsu.edu/sesug/2005/AD07_05.PDF)
- [Creating a Stored Macro Facility in Ten Minutes](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2008/101-2008.pdf)

**Here is what I have done so far:**

I have created a directory "C:\myMacros."  First, I create a program called "HelloWorld.sas" which contains the following code:

```
/* HelloWorld.sas */
option mstored sasmstore=mymacros;
libname myMacros 'C:\myMacros';

%macro HelloWorld() / store source;
    data _null_;
        put "Hello, World!";
    run;
%mend;
```

The code executes with the following log entry:

```
1    option mstored sasmstore=mymacros;
2    libname myMacros 'C:\myMacros';
NOTE: Libref MYMACROS was successfully assigned as follows:
      Engine:        V9
      Physical Name: C:\myMacros
3
4    %macro HelloWorld() / store source;
5        data _null_;
6            put "Hello, World!";
7        run;
8    %mend;
```

Within the SAS File Explorer, the Active Library "Mymacros" has been created in which resides catalog named "Sasmacr".  Checking within Windows Explorer, I see that "C:\myMacros\sasmacr.sas7bcat" has been created.  In the SAS File Explorer, I click on the "Sasmacr" catalog and find "Helloworld" inside.  When I double click on it, I get message box saying,

> No default action for the Macro data type.

Therefore, I conclude that the macro has been compiled and stored in the "Sasmacr" catalog.  I close out of SAS to clear all memory.

Now, I try to call the macro.  I open a new SAS session and create a new program titled "CallHelloWorld1.sas" which contains the following code:

```
/* CallHelloWorld1.sas */
libname myMacros 'C:\myMacros';
filename myCat catalog 'mymacros.sasmacr.helloworld.source';
%include myCat;

%HelloWorld();
```

This generates an error at the `%include` statement.

```
1    /* CallHelloWorld1.sas */
2    libname myMacros 'C:\myMacros';
NOTE: Libref MYMACROS was successfully assigned as follows:
      Engine:        V9
      Physical Name: C:\myMacros
3    filename myCat catalog 'mymacros.sasmacr.helloworld.source';
4    %include myCat;
ERROR: Physical file does not exist, SOURCE  .
ERROR: Cannot open %INCLUDE file MYCAT.
5
6    %HelloWorld();
     -
     180
WARNING: Apparent invocation of macro HELLOWORLD not resolved.

ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.
```

The error claims that the physical file doesn't exist, which contradicts my observation of it above. So, I conclude that I am calling it incorrectly.   According to [FILENAME Statement, CATALOG Access Method](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/68024/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0e720f80cp61wn1mplyz2xy2aeu.htm), a SAS four part name consists of *library.catalog.entry.entrytype*.  My statement consists of

1. The library: `myMacros` as defined by `libname myMacros 'C:\myMacros';`
2. The catalog: `sasmacr`
3. The entry: `helloworld`
4. The type: `source`

That is, `mymacros.sasmacr.helloworld.source`.  There must be an error in here, but I cannot fathom what it is.

To try another approach, again I close out of SAS to clear the memory.  I create "CallHelloWorld2.sas" which contains the following code:

```
/* CallHelloWorld2.sas */
libname myMacros 'C:\myMacros';
filename myCat catalog 'mymacros.sasmacr';
%include myCat(HelloWorld);

%HelloWorld();
```

This too produces an error at the `%include` line:

```
1    /* CallHelloWorld2.sas */
2    libname myMacros 'C:\myMacros';
NOTE: Libref MYMACROS was successfully assigned as follows:
      Engine:        V9
      Physical Name: C:\myMacros
3    filename myCat catalog 'mymacros.sasmacr';
4    %include myCat(HelloWorld);
ERROR: Entry HELLOWORLD.SOURCE not found in catalog MYMACROS.SASMACR.
ERROR: Cannot %INCLUDE member HelloWorld in the aggregate MYCAT.
ERROR: Entry HELLOWORLD.SOURCE not found in catalog MYMACROS.SASMACR.
ERROR: Cannot %INCLUDE member HelloWorld in the aggregate MYCAT.
5
6    %HelloWorld();
     -
     180
WARNING: Apparent invocation of macro HELLOWORLD not resolved.

ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.
```

It appears that either my macro has not been stored properly or that I am calling it incorrectly.  However, the resources are woefully inadequate.  Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
libname myMacros 'C:\temp';

option mstored sasmstore=mymacros;

%helloWorld()
```

That's all you need to do - remind SAS where you are pointing things and then run the macro.  You don't need to %include anything.

Comment: Thank you, but why doesn't it print the source to the log?  I've tried adding `source` or `mautosource` in varying combinations with `sasautos=libref` and `sasmstore=libref` to the `option` statement, but the macro source code does not print to the log even though the macro was saved with the source option.

Comment: Read that article you posted again ("Ways to store...").  `%COPY` is your answer, ultimately.

Comment: When I write `%copy HelloWorld / source;` it outputs the macro source to the log, but `HelloWorld` is highlighted in red as though it is an error.  Is my syntax incorrect and the log output a convenient side effect?  Or, is the syntax correct and the SAS highlighting misleading?

Comment: The syntax highlighter just doesn't have a rule for the %COPY macro statement. There are many valid SAS commands that the syntax highlighting doesn't understand.